# Can this multiple-entry Chinese visa still be used?

Tags: visas, china, multiple-entry

I went to China about 6 months ago for 10 days.  The visa issued for that occasion says:

```
Category: F
Entries: M-多
Duration of each stay: 060 days after each entry
```

The `Enter before` date has not yet passed.
Am I correct in thinking that I do not need to get a new visa for a second trip?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can enter again as long as the `Enter before` date has not been passed, that's the whole point of it.

I don't have an official link for this. I have been refused entry (into China) once specifically because that date had been passed (on a dual entry visa and the second entry)